# Raspberry PI - Send mail from command line using GMAIL smtp server

Tags: command-line, smtp, gmail, sendmail, raspberry-pi3

How can I send email from Raspberry Pi using my gmail account?

I would like to send mail from command line and use this method in my scripts.

Envirenment:

```
Hardware: Raspberry PI 3
OS: Jessie
SMTP: smtp.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use this method on my Raspberry Pi 3 devices:

**Google account setting**

1. Login to your gmail account
2. Go to: Settings -> Accounts and Import -> Other Google Account settings
3. Go to: Personal info & privacy -> Account overview
4. Go to: Sign-in & security -> Connect apps & sites
5. Set option Allow less secure apps to ON

**Install SSMTP**
    `sudo apt-get install ssmtp`

**Save original conf file**
    `sudo mv /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf.bak`

**Create new conf file** (with vi, or some other text editor)
    `sudo vi /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

**file content**

```
root=your_account@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=your_account@gmail.com
AuthPass=your_password
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES

# Debug=Yes
```

**Secure conf file**

```
sudo groupadd ssmtp
sudo chown :ssmtp /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

If you have error on this step like ''cannot access'' ... you must find ssmtp file and use that path: **sudo find / -name "ssmtp"**

```
sudo chown :ssmtp /usr/sbin/ssmtp
sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
sudo chmod g+s /usr/sbin/ssmtp
```

**Sending mail from (only one) command line**

```
echo "This is a test" | ssmtp recipient.address@some_domain.com
```

or

```
printf "To: recipient.address@some_domain.com\nFrom: RaspberryPi3\nSubject: Testing send mail from Raspberry\n\nThis is test. Best Regards!\n" | ssmtp -t
```

**Sending mail from file test.txt**
Make file with similar content:

```
To: recipient.address@some_domain.com
From: your_account@gmail.com
Subject: Testing send mail from Raspberry

This is test mail (body)

Best Regards!
```

Now you can send mail from file

```
ssmtp recipient.address@some_domain.com < test.txt
```

That's all :)

Comment: You should be submitting this to Code Review - you've been submitting answers posing as questions

Comment: Using the printf form of the command line with double quotes (as shown) results in the error: -bash: !\n: event not found
Use single quotes around the whole line (between printf and | ) instead, and it works.

Comment: This method of setting up your Gmail account is now superceded by the App Passwords process as described here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: When I try to send the email the command doesn't do anything and doesn't give any errors, I have to kill it with ctrl + z . any ideas what's wrong?